# Interchanging liminf and supremum under certain conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Suppose a situation whereby I know for some bounded collection $a_{m,n}$ of real numbers the following:

*For any $n \geq 1$, $\displaystyle\liminf_{m\to\infty} a_{m,n} \leq B_{n}$ and we can choose the $B_{n}$ such that $\sup_{n\geq 1}B_{n} <\infty$.*

Can I conclude that $\displaystyle\liminf_{m \to \infty} \left(\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{m,n}\right) \leq \sup_{n\geq 1} B_{n}$?

Counter-examples also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counter-example: let $a_{m, n} = \begin{cases} 1 & m \equiv n \pmod{2} \\ 0 & m \not \equiv n \pmod{2} \end{cases}$. This is clearly bounded. Then for a fixed $n$ we have $\liminf\limits_{m \to \infty} a_{m, n} = 0$ and so we can pick $B_n = 0$ and so $\sup\limits_{n \geq 1} B_n = 0$. However, for any fixed $m$ we have $\sup\limits_{n \geq 1} a_{m, n} = 1$ and so
$$
\liminf\limits_{m \to \infty} \left ( \sup\limits_{n \geq 1} a_{m, n} \right ) = \liminf\limits_{m \to \infty} 1  = 1 > 0 = \sup\limits_{n \geq 1} B_n.
$$.